# Why did Elijah pray seven times?

Tags: elijah, prayer

Elijah makes the statement

> “And at the time of the offering of the oblation, Elijah the prophet came near and said, "O Lord, God of Abraham, Isaac, and Israel, let it be known this day that you are God in Israel, and that I am your servant, and that **I have done all these things at your word**.”
>   ‭‭1 Kings‬ ‭18:36‬ ‭

(What things? Commanded no rain for 3 1/2 years or how to build the altar or both?)

When it came to the heavens giving rain again Elijah prays seven times.

> “So Ahab went up to eat and to drink. And Elijah went up to the top of Mount Carmel. And he bowed himself down on the earth and put his face between his knees. And he said to his servant, "Go up now, look toward the sea." And he went up and looked and said, "There is nothing." And he said, "Go again," **seven times**.”
>   ‭‭1 Kings‬ ‭18:42-43

Why was it necessary to pray at all even? Once ought to have been enough surely! God said He would do it.

> “And it came to pass after many days that **the word of the LORD came to Elijah**, in the third year, saying, “Go, present yourself to Ahab, and **I will send rain on the earth**.””
>   ‭‭I Kings‬ ‭18:1‬ ‭

Comment: The text does not say that Elijah prayed seven times. The text says that Elijah told his servant 'Go again' seven times.

Comment: That’s right @NigelJ he actually isn’t recorded to have uttered a prayer at all, just prostration. But the essence is the same. Why did he send his servant out seven time regardless of whether he was prostrating, praying or waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After many days the word of the LORD came to Elijah, in the third year, saying, “Go, show yourself to Ahab, and I will send rain upon the earth.” (1 Kings 18:1) [ESV]

While a literal reading suggests all that is necessary for rain, is for Elijah to show himself to Ahab, the events which follow show that is an incomplete understanding of the word of the LORD. Obviously when Elijah first shows himself to Ahab, there is no rain, nor is rain part of the discussion:

> <sup>17</sup> When Ahab saw Elijah, Ahab said to him, “Is it you, you troubler of Israel?” <sup>18</sup> And he answered, “I have not troubled Israel, but you have, and your father's house, because you have abandoned the commandments of the LORD and followed the Baals. <sup>19</sup> Now therefore send and gather all Israel to me at Mount Carmel, and the 450 prophets of Baal and the 400 prophets of Asherah, who eat at Jezebel's table.” (1 Kings 18)

The "*word of the LORD*" which Elijah received must have included the instructions to arrange the confrontation on Mount Carmel with the 450 prophets of Baal and 400 prophets of Asherah. Also, it is clear Ahab attributes the drought to Elijah, not to the LORD. For Ahab, Elijah is the cause of the drought. For Elijah, Ahab's leadership is the reason the LORD caused the drought. In other words, if rain came just as a result of Elijah appearing to Ahab, Ahab would continue to see this national disaster as something from Elijah, not as something from the LORD in response to Ahab's leadership of the nation.

The underlying cause of the drought was Ahab's actions: abandoning the commandments of the LORD. The proper way to bring the drought to an end should have come from Ahab. He should have turned away from the Baals and to the LORD; he should have rid the land of the prophets of the Baals and of Asherah. That is to say, in the same way Ahab's wrong actions caused the LORD to respond by withholding rain, Ahab's right actions would have caused the LORD to give rain.

The point is the LORD does act in response to a leader's actions. When Ahab fails to respond, despite the events on Mount Carmel, Elijah has the opportunity to take matters into his hands. Notice the LORD simply tells Elijah, "*I will send rain upon the earth.*" He doesn't say **when** He will do that. Obviously it did not happen immediately after the fire at Mount Carmel.

After ridding the land of the false prophets, Elijah could have simply "called it day" and wait for the rain which was sure to come. However, Elijah knows the LORD responds when a leader demonstrates they are committed to following the commandments of the LORD. What Elijah does next can be seen as something to cause the LORD to send rain right away, in response to Elijah.

The phrase, "*I will send rain upon the earth...*" recalls the first time the LORD sent rain:

> For in seven days I will cause it to rain on the earth for forty days and forty nights, and I will wipe from the face of the ground every living thing that I have made.” (Genesis 7:4)

In addition, the **waiting** period Noah is repeated two more times:

> He **waited** seven more days and then sent out the dove again from the ark. (Genesis 8:10)
>
> He **waited** another seven days and sent the dove out again, but it did not return to him this time. (Genesis 8:12)

Elijah knows seven days is the **normal** time to **wait** for rain, and it is the **normal** time man can wait. So rather then **wait** seven days for the rain which is sure to come, Elijah sends his servant seven times to look for rain. Elijah's actions demonstrate he knows the normal **wait time** for rain and for relief is seven days. By sending his servant to look for rain seven times on the same day, Elijah causes the LORD to respond and send the rain **that** day.

Comment: What I could agree with in your response and really liked was had Ahab repented then the curse would have been lifted. However I’m still struggling to bridge the gap that all answers to prayer after a drought takes seven days as a general rule. +1

Comment: @NihilSineDeo "I will send rain..." says the LORD. So it is not about the drought; it is about sending rain.

Comment: However I’m still struggling to bridge the gap that all answers to prayer for sending rain takes seven days as a general rule. @RevelationLad

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Nowhere does it say Elijah ever prayed for rain even one time. While he was looking at the ground with his face between his knees, he sent his servant seven times to look in the direction of the sea. Not only is prayer not mentioned, Elijah's posture is not consistent with prayer.

Comment: Yes except I take Scripture to be inspired including the NT *”Elijah was a man with a nature like ours, and he prayed fervently that it might not rain, and for three years and six months it did not rain on the earth. Then he prayed again, and heaven gave rain, and the earth bore its fruit.”
‭‭James‬ ‭5:17-18‬* @RevelationLad

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Does the phrase "πάλιν προσηύξατο" always mean "prayed seven times?" And does the phrase "προσευχῇ προσηύξατο" mean prayed more than seven times?

Comment: The point is he prayed, yes? Or do you deny that he prayed? “Again he made supplication” for the first Greek phrase and “supplication prayer” or insistent praying for the second Greek phrase you ask about in James, which yes denotes repetition, the exact amount is not specified but the Hebrew would have used the number seven for a reoccurring event, such as “the righteous man falls seven times”, or falls repeatedly. In the OT text the servant went a total of seven times and no more as best as I can tell.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo He prayed but when? If the LORD **answered** his prayer, than it was **before** he confronted Elijah. Once than LORD says He is going to send rain after showing himself to Ahab, all Elijah is required to do is what the LORD instructs.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers:

> Go again seven times.—From this delay of the answer to prayer Elijah’s
>   example became proverbial for intensity and perseverance in
>   supplication ([James 5:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%205%3A17&version=ESV)). The contrast is remarkable between the
>   immediate answer to his earlier prayer (see [1Kings 18:36-37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2018%3A36-37&version=NIV)) and the
>   long delay here. The one was for the sake of the people; the other for
>   some lesson—perhaps of humility and patience—to Elijah himself. When
>   the answer does come, it fulfils itself speedily. The “little cloud”
>   becomes all but immediately (for so “in the mean while” should be
>   rendered) a storm blackening the whole heavens, borne by a hurricane
>   from the west.

Comment: “the other for some lesson—perhaps of humility and patience—to Elijah himself.“ that is what I am attempting to find out. Some lesson, what is it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The truth here is not Elijah praying seven times or sending his servants seven times or waiting for seven days .

***The questions here are:*** Did God send the rain as he promised? Did the little cloud they saw later become a great and heavy rain that filled the land?

***The answer is yes, yes, yes, yes, yes.*** Our God is a promise and never fail God and what he say he will do he will do no matter the time. And we should know that God's time is the best, therefore the rain came at God's time and that was the best.

Comment: Welcome to BH community. A well  formatted answer will make an answer more shining, and an answer focused on to the questions as well.

Comment: I have not voted down this time, nor edited, but please do not use capitals in this way. Many people see this as 'shouting' and many are offended by it. Please use italics as emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

There is reason to mention Elijah's dramatic prayer to raise the  widow's son back to life (1Kings 17:17-24) I think this is a great prayer and part of the line of divine intervention through prayer in His ministry. God shows that not only does he have power over the elements, He also has power over all human life.

Comment: Hi Chima, welcome to the site. Could you add additional detail to your answer--it isn't clear to me that this answers the original question. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be time better spent praying for rain in places that have droughts and people are starving NOW? in present time .. ??? than all this discussing the details of something that happened a few thousand years ago, the ACTUAL indisputable truth of which will never actually be completely 100% clear as everyone has their own take on what it all really means !!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/48563)

Comment: @rose-Instead of asking questions, the Answer is for "answering." One must address the intent of the question in order to be a valid response.  Keep studying the Bible (and some commentaries).  It's great for the soul!